# Mark all items as read in Pocket (Read It Later)

Tags: pocket

For Google Reader I can just do "Mark All As Read" and all unread articles are checked off.
I'd like to do the same for getpocket.com (formerly Read It Later) but I don't see a button or something for it.

I'm now scrolling past 200 articles, then bulk editing them, but with 3K items to go I'm thinking: there must be a faster way to do this.

How can I "Mark all as read" in getpocket.com?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That’s not possible at the moment, as described here: 
http://help.getpocket.com/customer/portal/questions/383159-mark-all-read

Comment: I asked about this several months ago, and received a similar answer, as well.. so I don't expect it's on their roadmap.

Answer (score 11):

### Updated answer

I think there is a workaround to do this now.

1. Open Pocket in your browser (preferably list view)
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-click the first item in the list
3. Grab your scrollbar and drag it down. Since they have *infinite scrolling* now, you can load all items now. This will take some time if you have many items.
4. <kbd>Shift</kbd>-click the last items. All items between the first and last one will be selected as well
5. Hit *Archive*

### Old answer

I wondered if this functionality was added in the mean time and checked my Pocket. As far as I understand your question, this does work now. (I don't know what happens, if you have like 3000 items – if there is a pagination, it may just work for the first page)

1. In the toolbar at the bottom – click the **Bulk Edit** icon (the first one)
2. To select all items, click the **check box** right above to label *BULK EDIT*
3. Choose **Mark as read** from the Action select-box
4. Click **Save Changes**

Comment: It doesn't look like it to me. You still have to scroll and load all the items, then click the "select all" checkbox and then do "mark as read".

Answer (score 7):

I made an app that marks all of your pocket items as read. Hope it helps https://unqueue.herokuapp.com/

Comment: It's crazy to me that in nearly 7 years Pocket still has not added this functionality. Thanks for making your app!

Comment: @johan how did you know about this URL? I wasn't ready to publish, but if you say it's a good replacement, I am ready to publish! :)

Comment: Your old one doesn't work for me so definitely better ;) Thanks for making this. The only problem is the new one only archives 10 items. (instead of supposedly all items?)

Comment: Your old page has a 'Fork me on GitHub' button and your GitHub project has a link to the new app.

Comment: ah  yep i need to edit this bit: https://github.com/jshawl/unqueue/blob/master/client/src/hooks/usePocketApi.ts#L53

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I just archived thousands of articles.

Comment: awesome! I'll bump this up to > 1000 hopefully in the near future. let me know if there's anything I can do to make this better!

Answer (score 1):

Since no answer really worked for me.

This is a little script I wrote to bulk archive all entries.

Simply run it at the "Pocket" start page and grab a coffee, it will take its time to move all entries.

Here an uglyfied bookmarklet version to run in the browser address bar

```
javascript:var archiveAllTimeout=null,archiveEntries=()=>{var a=document.querySelectorAll("article");if((a||[]).length){for(var b=0;b<a.length;b++)a[b]&&a[b].click();setTimeout(()=>{var b=document.querySelector(".css-11yd3hn button.css-mlr9nc:nth-of-type(3)");b&&b.click();archiveAllTimeout=setTimeout(archiveEntries,1e3)},1e3)}else clearTimeout(archiveAllTimeout),setTimeout(()=>{alert("All items archived");var b=document.querySelector(".css-mk5p2j button.css-1ogf4l3");b&&b.click()},1e3)};setTimeout(()=>{document.querySelector("a[href=\"/\"]").click(),setTimeout(()=>{document.querySelector(".css-15l7u4z .css-mk5p2j button.css-mlr9nc:nth-of-type(3)").click()},1e3)},100),archiveAllTimeout=setTimeout(archiveEntries,100);
```

Here the pretty version for the developer console

```
var archiveAllTimeout=null
var archiveEntries=()=>{
    var all=document.querySelectorAll('article')
    if((all||[]).length){
        for(var i=0;i<all.length;i++){if(all[i]){all[i].click()}}
        setTimeout(()=>{var a=document.querySelector(/*Archive button*/'.css-11yd3hn button.css-mlr9nc:nth-of-type(3)');if(a){a.click()};archiveAllTimeout=setTimeout(archiveEntries,1000)},1000)
    } else {
        clearTimeout(archiveAllTimeout)
        setTimeout(()=>{alert('All items archived');/** finish bulk edit */var a=document.querySelector(/*End Bulk Edit button*/'.css-mk5p2j button.css-1ogf4l3');if(a){a.click()}},1000)
    }
}

setTimeout(()=>{
    /** make sure list is selected*/ document.querySelector('a[href="/"]').click()
    setTimeout(()=>{/** start bulk edit */document.querySelector(/*Bulk Edit button*/'.css-15l7u4z .css-mk5p2j button.css-mlr9nc:nth-of-type(3)').click()},1000)
},100)
archiveAllTimeout=setTimeout(archiveEntries,100)
```

Comment: Thanks! I needed to delete a bunch, so I used these two lines to select 25 at a time by running it directly from the developer console after going into bulk edit mode on the desired tag and then manually confirming after running the script multiple times to select groups of 25:

`var all=document.querySelectorAll('article'); for(var i=0;i<all.length;i++){if(all[i]){all[i].click()}}`  Clumsy, but quicker than me trying to do the perfect modification of your great script. It got me started!

Comment: The above script no longer work. Can anyone provide an update?

Comment: `var all=document.querySelectorAll('button[data-cy="Archive"]'); for(var i=0;i<all.length;i++){if(all[i]){all[i].click()}}` now you have to find all the buttons that contain the `data-cy = "Archive"` attribute

Comment: interestingly I got blocked by their servers, probably too many requests :)

Answer (score -1):

With the addon/extension 'Pick Pocket".  Its not as simple as one click and done, but it is light speed compared to 3 click to delete on article.  Get pick pocket, I swap to list view to load more files at once, then use the bulk edit, select all, action: delete, save changes (all located at the bottom) series of clicks to take out around 50 entries per routine.

Comment: Delete is not the same as mark read.

Answer (score -1):

On a Mac, in Chrome, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+click the first item. Then scroll down to the last item. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+click last item → all items should go yellow. Scroll back up to top and click the archive button.

Comment: As I said in the question: scrolling past them takes too long for my amount of articles saved.